# Reference Shared class in XAML for Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am creating a universal app and I am having a hard time trying to bind my settings controls to a shared Settings class. How do I reference my Settings class in order to set the binding source on my controls?

XAML Code:

```
<Page
x:Class="DownloaderUniversal.SettingsPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DownloaderUniversal"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel>
        <!-- Content Section 1-->
            <StackPanel>

                <!-- Section 1 header -->
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="Save Location" />

                <!-- Section 1 body -->
                <RadioButton x:Name="music" Content="Music Library" IsChecked="{Binding Source={Static Resource SharedSettings}, Path=MusicFolderSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="Music_Checked"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="sdCard" Content="SD Card" IsChecked="{Binding Source={Static Resource SharedSettings}, Path=CardFolderSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="Card_Checked"/>

            </StackPanel>
```

and my Settings class:

```
class Settings
{
    // Our local storage settings
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings;

    // The local storage key names of our settings
    const string musicFolderKeyName = "musicRadioButton";
    const string cardFolderKeyName = "cardRadioButton";

    // The default value of our settings
    const bool musicFolderDefault = true;
    const bool cardFolderDefault = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that gets the application settings.
    /// </summary>
    public Settings()
    {
        try
        {
            localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            // Get the settings for this application.
            //isolatedStore = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update a setting value for our application. If the setting does not
    /// exist, then add the setting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;

        // If the key exists
        //if (localSettings.Contains(Key))
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(Key))
        {
            // If the value has changed
            if (localSettings.Values[Key] != value)
            {
                // Store the new value
                localSettings.Values[Key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise create the key.
        else
        {
            localSettings.Values.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }

        return valueChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current value of the setting, or if it is not found, set the 
    /// setting to the default setting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="valueType"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="Key"></param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public valueType GetValueOrDefault<valueType>(string Key, valueType defaultValue)
    {
        valueType value;

        // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(Key))
        {
            value = (valueType)localSettings.Values[Key];
        }
        // Otherwise, use the default value.
        else
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }

        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to get and set a Directory Folder Setting Key.
    /// </summary>
    public bool MusicFolderSetting
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(musicFolderKeyName, musicFolderDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(musicFolderKeyName, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to get and set a Directory Folder Setting Key.
    /// </summary>
    public bool CardFolderSetting
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(cardFolderKeyName, cardFolderDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(cardFolderKeyName, value);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on where you create your shared instance.

One possible solution: Create it in App.xaml as a resource.

App.xaml:

```
<App.Resources>
    <local:Settings x:Key="SharedSettings" />
</App.Resources>
```

Page.xaml:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SharedSettings}}">...
```

This is the simplest solution. Mostly, you wouldn't create the instance directly in the app resources, but have a service locator that there that handles it for you.

Comment: thanks for the response. I did what you suggested and set the source binding of my radiobuttons to `SharedSettings`, but its still not binding correctly. The first radio button should show up as checked when i navigate to the page. I've updated my xaml code.

Comment: I figured it out. Needed to add `Source={Static Resource SharedSettings}` directly to the control item. Thanks for the help.